# How to return data from an infinite loop without breaking it in python?

Tags: python

**Purpose**: I want to read the content of an infinite loop [class A], collect data, and send it off to another class B/function for further processing.

**Problem**: content in class A can be displayed. However, calling A's content into class B/function display empty list.

There are **2 files**: **test3.py** and **test4.py**. The call and execution are *done from test4.py*

It should work, but it does not: Looking for advice, what is wrong? - Thanks.

```
# Test4.py
import test3
import time
objectTest = test3.test1()
def interface():
   A = objectTest.collectData() #call collectData from tset3
   B = (objectTest.name)        #call Instance attribute from test3
   print(B)                     #for testing purpose
   print(A)                     #for testing purpose
   while True:
       interface()
       time.sleep(1)

# Test3.py
import random
import time

class test1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name=[]

    def collectData(self):
        temp=[]
        #temp = list(self.name)  # for testing purpose
        enter code heretemp = self.name.copy()
        print(temp)             # for testing purpose
        return temp

    def engine(self):
        while True:
            self.name.append(random.randrange(1,20))
            self.collectData()
            self.name.clear()
            time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    object1 = test1()
    object1.engine()
```

Comment: Please be more specific on what does not work as expected. Pasting you (example) code is already a good way to ensure others can help you! 

I am not sure what problem you're facing. (What error messages are you seeing? What exact output are you expecting / seeing?)

Comment: Read about [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators)

Comment: Hey basti, I have a processing going through an infinite while loop. Data need to be sent out from the infinite loop to another program for further processing. Obviously, we cannot use "return" within the infinite loop. As suggested Stovfl, generators can be used, but still looking for better ways. Hope I made it clear.

Comment: @eva: ***"what is wrong?"***: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at `enter code heretemp = self.name.copy()`. [Edit] your question and correct it.

Comment: @stovfl: executing test4.py, which calls test3.py, there is no way I can display the attribute value. It appears empty (list). Yes, generator is one way, using queue is another one. I am planning to use queue in multithread processing. Thanks